# Change font or point colour based on absolute path of the source file

Tags: hooks, faces, point

This is a rare occasion when I need it, but I am trying to figure out a way to change colour of font/point based on the path of source file to easily distinguish which file I am editing when I am working on two similar repositories.

(E.g. based on files from */some/path/local_master* and */some/path/remote_master*).

Any advice?

Comment: It might be easier to have two separate frames, one for each repo, i.e. use location on the screen rather than color to distinguish them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a directory-local variable. [Relevant documentation node](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html#Directory-Variables).

To use this, you create a file `.dir-locals.el` in the root of each project dir with contents like:

```
     ((nil . ((my/is-local . t))))
```

Then in your config you need to do two things, you need to set the variable as safe so Emacs doesn't prompt you about it whenever it loads a file in that directory, and you need to modify your display however you want based on it. Below is an example:

```
;; Mark any boolean value as safe.
;; See https://stackoverflow.com/q/19806176/4851078
(put 'my/is-local 'safe-local-variable #'booleanp)

;; Set unfontified text in buffers from the local repo to dark blue
;; See https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FacesPerBuffer
(add-hook 'find-file-hook
          #'(lambda ()
              (when (bound-and-true-p my/is-local)
                (buffer-face-set '(:foreground "#003")))))
```